# Difference between Structure elements and Structure Members

Tags: .net, vb.net

In the MSDN documentation ([Structures Vs Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/structures-and-classes)) where they discuss similarities of classes and structures, the following is stated:

> Both have members, which can include constructors, methods, properties, fields, constants, enumerations, events, and event handlers. However, do not confuse these members with the declared *elements* of a structure.

Can someone please explain that for a structure in VB, what is the difference between an element of a structure and a member of a structure? The documentation quoted above says that we should not confuse them... and I am very much confused.

Comment: Did you click the link in the menu on the left entitled [Declared Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/)? That seems the obvious thing to do if you want more information on the subject.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I did! And I'm still not sure what the quote is trying to say (that's why I edited the question to include the emphasis on just _"elements"_ which makes it even more confusing). If you are, can you please elaborate (perhaps in an answer)?

Comment: It's probably more clear here: [Structures and Other Programming Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/structures-and-other-programming-elements)

Comment: I checked both links. Whats confusing to me is that they have mentioned literally everything that can be declared as "elements" - variables, constants, enumerations, classes, structures, modules, interfaces, procedures, procedure parameters, function returns, external procedure references, operators, properties, events, and delegates. So if everything is an element then what is a member? - thats my confusion!

Comment: I think it means: A member is an element, not every element is a member. It's confusing because they use the term element later themselves

Comment: If you follow that link I posted further on, the `Structures and Objects` and `Structures and Procedures` makes it more clear what are the Members and what are the Elements that can be used/instantiated but are not Members.

Comment: **Update:** The problematic sentence has been removed from the docs. From the GitHub issue created by the OP: [_"Docs have been updated to drop that sentence, and it will show up on the site as soon as it flows through the system"_](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/23921#issuecomment-827010283) and [_"Neither Kathleen nor I could figure out what difference was supposedly highlight between members and elements. It added confusion without adding any information"_](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/23938#issue-623525294).